# interpreting JUnit test results?

Tags: java, junit, testng, mockito

I have a method with `(excpected = NumberFormatException.class)`

Method:

```
@Test(expected=NumberFormatException.class)
public void testAssignCasesWithInvalidMemberId() throws IOException {
    when(info.getUID()).thenReturn(invalidId);
    when(request.getParameter("ac")).thenReturn(validCIds);
    custObj.assignNums();
}
```

And I get this the following as the result of executing the method:

```
Expected exception: java.lang.NumberFormatException
junit.framework.AssertionFailedError: Expected exception: java.lang.NumberFormatException
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.ExpectException.evaluate(ExpectException.java:32)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:271)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:70)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:50)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:238)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:63)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:236)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:53)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:229)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)
at org.mockito.internal.runners.JUnit45AndHigherRunnerImpl.run(JUnit45AndHigherRunnerImpl.java:37)
at org.mockito.runners.MockitoJUnitRunner.run(MockitoJUnitRunner.java:62)
at junit.framework.JUnit4TestAdapter.run(JUnit4TestAdapter.java:38)
at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.optional.junit.JUnitTestRunner.run(JUnitTestRunner.java:532)
at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.optional.junit.JUnitTestRunner.launch(JUnitTestRunner.java:1179)
at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.optional.junit.JUnitTestRunner.main(JUnitTestRunner.java:1030)
```

In the `assignNums()` method, invlidId is getting converted to Long, and throws exception.

My question is understanding the result text.

TestNG output for the same code as something like `Expected xyz exceptiong, but this test method blah blah`. Gives enough info about what it expects and what is actual.

But in JUnit case, it does not say anything other than Expected xyz exception. Whether it got some other exception or did not get Exception at all, which TestNG says.

Comment: It tells you that method run without the exception it wanted. So the test failed. It is enough details for you to start finding out why it did not do it and fix the test, no ?

Comment: @kiruwka Does the above trace tell anything about "did not return anything" or "Did return some other exception as apposed to expected one"?

Comment: No, obviously it doesn't. I guess it just indicates that method finished without having a chance to catch expected exception. If you want to differentiate between "no exception" or "other type of exception" you could check it yourself manually, but, again, what is the difference ? You still have to fix why it does not throw what needed.

Comment: Hmmm.. `you can check it yourself manually`. And the difference exists. In general terms. "Hey, I expected xyz, but I got abc" and "Hey I expected xyz, but I did not get anything" vs "Hey I expected this"

Comment: more vs "Hey I expected this but I did not get it(for whatever reason). Now go and fix me so that I get what I expect"

Comment: @kiruwka you got the point. The trace does not taell me this "but I did not get it(for whatever reason)". However, I got your point :-). Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

No, in this case JUnit will not tell you specifically what was thrown (if anything was thrown at all). It simply reports that you expected an exception to be thrown and that exception was not thrown. So, the test failed. Agreed that a little more information would be helpful.

Comment: `and that exception was not thrown.` ==> Is this implicit? Because trace doesn't seem to indicate this.

Comment: the trace doesnt show the exception was thrown, so the excpetion was not thrown. otherwise in a "success" unit test case the exception will be reported to the console and your test will report as passed.